# How to hide/remove Picklist Value in a Visual Force Page

Tags: visualforce

I have a required picklist value but I could not able to figured out why the `--None` value is embedded to the picklist, how can i remove thae `--none--` value?

[image]

```
<apex:inputField value="{!employee__c.ranking__c}" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just want to extend @Praveen answer:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}" id="stageId"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function(){
                var e = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="stageId"]')[0];
                if (e && !e[0].value) {e.remove(0);}
            })();
            </script>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

We don't have to load jQuery library here.

Comment: Have you tested? its not working , i even tried `^=` starts with

Comment: if you inspect element, you will smth like :j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:stageId; id$= will look for everything which ends with stageId and yes it works in firefox and chrome

Comment: yes i understand your code but when I look at my element I'm not getting the name at the end instead `id="j_id0:j_id4:j_id6:j_id13:j_id14` and i feel uncomfortable putting the id that might change.

Comment: full path is dynamic, but it will always contain id of the element in the end if id was specified: j_id0:stageId, j_id0:j_id1:stageId, etc. if you add id to page as 'p' and id to from as 'f', path will look like p:f:stageId, look at [Iterating with Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)

Comment: ah I totally forgot about adding the id to it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by using the Schema.DescribeFieldResult Salesforce standard class to retrieve all the possible field label value pairs for a picklist field. The retrieved value pairs are then stored inside a collection of select option objects, which can be used as the basis of a select list. Below is a snapshot of the code from the apex controller, and also the Visualforce page.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="NoNoneForPicklistController">

    Please select required status:
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!invoiceStatement.Status__c}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!statusOptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>  

</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class NoNoneForPicklistController{

    public Invoice_Statement__c invoiceStatement {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> statusOptions {get;set;}

    // Constructor called when page is accessed.
    public NoNoneForPicklistController() {

        invoiceStatement = new Invoice_Statement__c();        
        statusOptions = new List<SelectOption>();

        // Use DescribeFieldResult object to retrieve status field.
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult statusFieldDescription =                     Invoice_Statement__c.Status__c.getDescribe();

        // For each picklist value, create a new select option
        for (Schema.Picklistentry picklistEntry:                                statusFieldDescription.getPicklistValues()){

            statusOptions.add(new SelectOption(                                     pickListEntry.getValue(),pickListEntry.getLabel()));

            // obtain and assign default value
            if (picklistEntry.defaultValue){
                invoiceStatement.Status__c = pickListEntry.getValue();
            }  
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: no, why would you want to write 10+ lines of code to remove the value of none? which is salesforce forcefully embedding in the picklist.... i believe there should be a better solution then writing code for that.

Comment: another option which I am thinking of using javascript.

Comment: I agree it's too much work, it's just the server-side approach. The client-side approach has its own issues.

Comment: yah agree. I am just thinking use case why he is looking for removing None Option when this is required picklist

Comment: here is the link of the above source code, i was expecting that @Devendra would have done instead copying and pasting. Give credit where credit is due .... http://christopheralunlewis.blogspot.com/2010/10/creating-picklist-in-visualforce-page.html

Comment: @AdrianLarson can you advise what the main issues on the client-side approach are? Thanks

Comment: @Andy You have to worry about cross-browser support if you do it client side. Also Salesforce frowns on DOM manipulation and considers it a security risk.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do it in client side using javascript, rather than using Apex describe calls constructing your own select options.
 Using jquery, you can remove the first option (`-None-`) like this:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountController">
    <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"/>
    <script>
        j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready( function () {
            j$('option[value=""]').remove();
        });

        <apex:form>
            <apex:inputField value="{!employee__c.ranking__c}" />
        </apex:form>
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can do it using `styleClass` but you have to load .JS

Just an another flavor

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
    <apex:form>
        <script type='text/javascript' src= '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'>
        </script>
        <script language="javascript">
            $(function() {        
                $('select.RemoveNone option[value=]').remove();       
            });
        </script>    
        <apex:inputField styleClass="RemoveNone" value="{!Lead.LeadSource}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```